# How do I change the theme on an array of graphs using VlnPLot in Seurat (in R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I have data from an RNA seq and I am trying to visualise several genes in a violin plot with a certain theme.
When I run my command, the theme is however only applied to the last violin plot of the last gene (in this case BBS1).
How can I apply the theme to all the figures?

I tried this code:

```
VlnPlot(EMFAF, features=c("FAT1","GAPDH", "NPHP1", "BBS1"), group.by="Library",
               pt.size=0) +
  theme_minimal()
```

This to also try and adjust more than the theme but also here only the graph of the last gene is edited.

```
DotPlot(EMFAF, features=integrin_genes, group.by = "Library") +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8), 
          axis.title=element_text(size=10,face="bold"))
```

Comment: `Warning message:
In data(EMFAF) : data set ‘EMFAF’ not found`